# How to make each files downloadable using php

Tags: php

I am getting file list using a php function. It displays all the files in a directory as table on a php page.

[image]

How to make those file downloadable clicking on each file name?

The actual files will be of .tar.gz extension.

Thank You!

**My Function:**

```
function getFileList($dir)
  {
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open pointer to directory and read list of files
    $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      // skip hidden files
      if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
      if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$entry/",
          "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => 0,
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$entry",
          "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      }
    }
    $d->close();

    return $retval;
    $dirlist = getFileList("backupfiles");
  }
```

**My code:**

```
<?PHP
    // output file list in HTML TABLE format
    echo "<table id=\"ct\" border=\"1\">\n";
    echo "<thead>\n";
    echo "<tr id = \"ct_sort\"><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Size</th>                
    <th>Added On</th></tr>\n";
    echo "</thead>\n";
    echo "<tbody>\n";
    foreach($dirlist as $file) {
      echo "<tr>\n";
      echo "<td>{$file['name']}</td>\n";
      echo "<td>{$file['type']}</td>\n";
      echo "<td>{$file['size']}</td>\n";
      echo "<td>",date('r', $file['lastmod']),"</td>\n";
      echo "</tr>\n";
   }
    echo "</tbody>\n";
    echo "</table>\n\n";
?>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to echo a hyperlink to an existing file?

Comment: Yes... user will just click on the file name and it will get downloaded.

Comment: In that case, in the foreach, you would just do something like `echo "<td><a href='{$file['url']}'>{$file['name']}</a></td>\n";` assuming that your url is in `$file['url']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: This is the answer from my original comment.*

In the foreach, you would just change `echo "<td>{$file['name']}</td>\n";` to:

```
echo "<td><a href='{$file['url']}'>{$file['name']}</a></td>\n";
```

Assuming that your url is in `$file['url']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://www.yoursite.com/folder/{$file['name']}'>{$file['name']}</a></td>\n";
```

instead of:

```
echo "<td>{$file['name']}</td>\n";
```

Comment: Your solution is similar to what David suggested and also correct. But I will mark David's answer as correct as he answered it much before in the comments. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an anchor `<a>` tag inside of the `<td>{$file['name']}</td>\n` like so: `echo "<td><a href=\"{$file['path_to_file']}\">{$file['name']}</a></td>\n"` where `path_to_file` is the variable holding the path to your file from your database. Notice the the three levels of quotations.

Comment: This didn't work... my path to files is not in database... I have mentioned the path in a variable `$dirlist = getFileList("backupfiles");`. After adding your code, only one file is shown ofcourse with a hyperlink.